# Is there a simple way to select and copy 1 or 2 columns of an HTML table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, clipboard

I've heard that there's a button you can hold to drag a selection of a table column in Firefox, but I'm looking for a cross-browser answer.  I'm wondering if maybe I can put radio buttons above the columns, have the visitor select them, then, on the click of a button, have the columns copied to their clipboard.  I'm sure many have come across this problem; anyone with a good solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't reliably set the clipboard from HTML cross browser.  Flash can do it though.

http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/system/System.html#setClipboard%28%29

Comment: Do you think that I could make a flash button, for example, that could dynamically pull the data from an html table column?

Comment: @bozdoz, sure, you can make a flash button that calls out to a JS method which can use dom/jquery to get the data and then use setClipboard() to copy it to the clipboard.